# to list out my submenus of particular menu only in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. Want to show my sub menus on by left sidebar with links on my main menus page.
2. I used this code

   post_title; 
   wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=$menu_name&depth=2'); 
   ?>
3. Any help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this plugin: [JQuery Accordion Menu Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/)

Create the menu you want using WordPress Menu (Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus) and use the above plugin to display your menu on sidebar with Accordion effect. :)

**UPDATE**

The following code List Sub-Pages, if you are on a parent page and have some child. Place this code on your `sidebar.php`

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

Check [this wordpress codex section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages) for more details

Comment: No it didn't suit my need.please suggest me any wordpress codex

Comment: Can you explain what your actual need. You wants to list some menu items on the sidebar or...? please explain in detail.

Comment: i want to list out the submenus(or sub pages) of the current menu(or page).i am using this code <?php wp_page_menu('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID); ?>

Comment: i changed the code to :<ul><?php wp_page_menu('title_li=&child_of=$post->ID'); ?> </ul> Its listing all my pages and subpages instead of my current page's sub pages.

Comment: Really i am in need of some one to help me.When,i echoed my $post->ID,it showed my current page's id correctly.Then,what would be the problem?

Comment: want to list out in my left sidebar

Comment: So you wants to Display current parent and its sub-menu only on sidebar, right?

Comment: its showing nothing.but after editing this $current_page = $post->post_title; if($current_page==$post->post_parent),it again listed all my site's pages and subpages

Comment: I faced a similar problem earlier and solved it using the above code only. [Check this WordPress forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-current-parent-and-its-sub-menu-only-on-sidebar?replies=6)

Comment: ok i will check this forum and come back to u.thx for ur responses.

Comment: Yet i didn't got the solution.

Comment: got the fix through the Libin's code.Thanks a lot.I forgot to select the parent page for my child pages in dashboard->Pages->New Pages->parentname(instead of no parent).I made the change and applied your code.It worked out for me.Thanks

Comment: sry it was my mistake.ur solution did the trick.Once again very much.Struggling frm yesterday.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14795/discussion-between-libin-and-vijaya-narayanasamy)